# python - how to loop a selection menu until input is within range

Tags: python-3.x

im new to python.
I tried to search for this issue but all i found is Java discussions.

i need to print out a selection menu like:

1. bla bla 1
2. bla bla 2
3. bla bla 3

i need it to run until the input is within range but i need it to be a function that takes 3 argument (lower_limit, upper_limit, user_input).
that way i could call the function and send it the specific limits i need to check each time.

so i run this code:

```
number_input = input("\nPlease choose a game to play: ")
game_selected = check_input_between_range(1,3,number_input)
```

to call for the checking function with the 3 arguments (this time the limits are 1 and 3)

```
def check_input_between_range(lower_limit, upper_limit, user_input):
try:
    if lower_limit <= int(user_input) <= upper_limit:
        print("user_input is inside the limits")
        return user_input
    else:
        print("input is out of limits\n")
except ValueError:
    print("user_input is not int")
except TypeError:
    print("user_input is not int")
print("check function finished")
```

but i cant figure out how to make to loop util the values are within range because if i call the function again in the `else:` block it fires up a different instance of the function so in the end it returns a result for each time the loop was run.

maybe im missing something basic here.
will appreciate some assistance.

thanks in advance.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in that direction.
i'll read that discussion and adapt it into my code (might take me a while lol)

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_input_between_range(lower_limit, upper_limit, user_input):
    try:
        if lower_limit <= int(user_input) <= upper_limit:
            print("user_input is inside the limits")
            return user_input
        else:
            print("input is out of limits\n")
    except ValueError:
        print("user_input is not int")
    except TypeError:
        print("user_input is not int")
    print("check function finished")


lower_limit =1
uper_limit = 3
number_input = input("\nPlease choose a game to play: ")
try:
    number_input = int(number_input)
    while number_input > lower_limit and number_input < uper_limit:
        game_selected = check_input_between_range(lower_limit, uper_limit, number_input)
        number_input = int(input("\nPlease choose a game to play: "))
    if number_input <= lower_limit or number_input >= uper_limit:
        print("input is out of limits\n")
except ValueError:
    print("user_input is not int")
except TypeError:
    print("user_input is not int")
```

Try this out I just keep your function as it is so that you can understand easily

Here is reduced code with modification in your function

```
def check_input_between_range(lower_limit, upper_limit, user_input):
    if lower_limit <= int(user_input) <= upper_limit:
        print("user_input is inside the limits")


lower_limit =1
uper_limit = 3
number_input = input("\nPlease choose a game to play: ")
try:
    number_input = int(number_input)
    while number_input > lower_limit and number_input < uper_limit:
        game_selected = check_input_between_range(lower_limit, uper_limit, number_input)
        number_input = int(input("\nPlease choose a game to play: "))
    if number_input <= lower_limit or number_input >= uper_limit:
        print("input is out of limits\n")
except ValueError:
    print("user_input is not int")
except TypeError:
    print("user_input is not int")
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time and explaining it with my own code..
i'll go over it and the discussion pointed above and adapt it into my code (might take me a while lol)

Comment: Mark as accepted if it works